# Developing Wordpress using https on local machine

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, web, xampp

So I've taken on a project to develop some features, fix the ui etc. for a wordpress site that has already gone live. I would like to develop from my local machine (windows 10).

I've exported a local copy of the database and pulled all the code onto my local machine via ftp. However, there seems to a bunch of url rewrite rules for https in place and existing urls pointing to https that's causing scripts and styles to not be found and pages to not load. I want to try and avoid changing urls in the database so that I don't have to change them back when deploying.

**Here is what I tried first:**

- Use XAMPP with port 80 exposing my site.
- Add an entry into my windows host file mapping 127.0.0.1 to example.com
- Changed Home and SiteURL from https://example.com to http://example.com

The problem is that whenever I try to navigate to any other page in the site, it automatically redirects me from http://example.com/about to https://example.com/about (which can't be found because I'm using port 80) and as mentioned earlier certain scripts and styles aren't being loaded. I'm not really sure where this url rewrite rule could be located as I am inheriting this code base.

**Here is what I tried after:**

- Use XAMPP with port 443 exposing my site.
- Add an entry into my windows host file mapping 127.0.0.1 to example.com
- Changed Back Home and SiteURL from http://example.com to https://example.com

The problem here is that when I navigate to https://example.com I get page could not be found. I then tried example.com:443 it redirected me to https:example.com which again could not be found.

**Question:**
Is there any possible way to develop locally using https to avoid having to update URLs in the database??
If not then where in WP would a url rewrite rule to rewrite http to https be located?

Comment: Is there an .htaccess file in the web root?

Comment: you can use a a plugin like: https://el.wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ to  change all urls to database as you want. Like  http://example.com  , else look at your htaccess. maybe it has some rules that you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Please check inside your `wp-config.php` if there is something like `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` defined. If yes, disable.

Then login via `http://example.com/wp-admin`

Then check for any SSL plugins that enforce SSL, and disable them.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah just set it to false but didn't seem to make a difference. Doing a find in my exported sql script there are 1000s of references to https ://example.com